# Need a hint on adjusting screen gamma permanently

Tags: ubuntu, display, gamma

Good time of day everyone!

I'm facing this problem with my Ubuntu 12.04.1 and a new ViewSonic monitor. The trouble is that the monitor has it's default gamma value set too high and there is no way I can adjust it by monitor hardware controls.

So far I've been using the `xgamma -gamma .75` command to get a comfortable picture. The problem is that after the system is locked or after I go to the "Switch User" menu gamma is reset back to 1.0 level. What can I do to adjust it once and for all?

UPD: I tried to use `lprof` to create a new `*.icm` and to load it with `gnome-color-manager`, but I don't see any difference between the new and the default one. I don't even know if the profile had been applied correctly.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: @Joost, nope, sorry. Switched to OS X a few years ago, so this question is no longer of interest to me (for now).

Comment: Aw! Im currently making that switch in the other direction.